# Highlight values repeated in subsequent columns

Tags: vba

I would like a cell to become highlighted if its value is present in each of the other columns.

Below is the part of the code that I can make work.  I've tried nesting additional *For-loops* to represent new columns, but this doesn't work because it counts the cells in the original column, and ends up highlighting everything.  I've also changed the *If* line to:

```
If Cells(i,1)=Cells(j,2)=Cells(k,3) Then
```

but this doesn't work either. Below is the code:

```
Sub check()
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 2) Then
                Cells(i, 1).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                End With
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to highlight if the value is duplicate anywhere in the range or only if the value is duplicate in the exact next column?

Comment: I would like a cell to become highlighted if its value is present in each of the other columns.  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Why does *Conditional Formatting* not work for your case? Why use VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub check()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim chkRng As Range
    Dim Srch As String
    Dim CurCol As Long

        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set chkRng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        For CurCol = 1 To LastCol
            For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
            Srch = Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value
            Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = ""
            If Not chkRng.Find(Srch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                With Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                End With
                Else
            End If
            Cells(CurRow, CurCol).Value = Srch
            Next CurRow
        Next CurCol

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note this checks the entire range for duplicates.